# Poor image quality when using fit-in filter of AWS's Serverless Image Handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm exploring the use of AWS's Serverless Image Handler solution for my cloudfront setup. I've followed the documentation provided here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pdfs/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/serverless-image-handler.pdf#template

After uploading an image, I've noticed a discrepancy in image quality when using the /fit-in/240x240 filter compared to styling the image directly to 240x240 pixels. The quality is noticeably poorer with the filter.

I'm seeking advice on how to obtain an optimized 240x240 image with good quality, similar to when the source image is styled directly to 240x240 pixels.

For reference, you can see the difference in image quality on my website here:
https://volk.lv/images/

Any insights or suggestions on optimizing image quality with the Serverless Image Handler would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!